# VS Code. How to open JSON settings with defaults

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm opening settings using **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)** I'm getting screen like this:

[image]

But in VSCode videos/tutorials I see people somehow have splitted window, with default settings on the left and user/workspace setting on the right:

[image]

How I can enable it?

===========================

**EDIT:**

I found **"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings"** option and set it to `true`, but still my UI is different from desired on screenshot above ( I don't see search box for searching settings, also I don't see the message `Place your settings in the right ... to override`):

[image]

Comment: yes, you have to use default settings to see this. it becaose of some last updates (not sure what exactly). idk why they changed it

Comment: and you can downgreade vs code. for example https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30 there you will see the settings like on your image

Answer (score 29):

As mentioned @Juraj Kocan  in comments, it happens after last VS Code updates.

This is [Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64932) related to this new "feature"

[This one helped me](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64932#issuecomment-462959522):

```
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
```

Answer (score 24):

### How to Get to the JSON settings in Newer Versions of VS Code

In the latest versions of VS Code, you can convert back to the split JSON settings editor by changing the following settings in the (now standard) UI settings editor:

1. Workbench > Settings: Editor

   - Change from `UI` to `json`
2. Workbench > Settings: Use Split JSON

   - Checkmark to enable the option

[image]

after making this change, VS Code will open its settings as a JSON file, like in older versions of the application, rather than in the new UI. This allows you to make the changes that other answers provide, directly in the JSON (if you can find the right place and file to make them in..)

---

**NOTE:** Whether or not you actually ***want*** to use the JSON settings is a different question. Most of the time, the settings search function allows finding the same settings in the new UI. Sometimes it is difficult to get search to work though, especially if the settings are worded differently in the new UI style. There may also be cases where extensions haven't been updated to accommodate the new UI setting style, and so there is no option but to enter the JSON directly.

Comment: This works as of now 2022

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by "Default".

steps to open setting by keyboard are:

1. press Ctrl+p (an input command line would appear at the top.)
2. press > 
   A List will appear like that in image. (search `preference` for all `vs code settings`)

[image]

Comment: On my 2nd image you can see that other people have `Default settings` on the left. It serves like hints. Also I saw people can click on any option and choose `copy to user settings` (and it will be copied to the right - to the user/workspace settings).