# VS Code settings not opening correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code

since a few weeks now I can't open my settings correctly in visual studio code. Before this issue, two windows appeared. One with the default settings and one with the edited settings. Now only the window with the edited settings shows up.

This is some of really annoying, because I want to search for a specific default setting, but can't click on the pen to edit it. I can't change it from the ui settings as well.

I append a screenshot of how it looks in my vs code:
[new settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyXYF.png)

This is how it looked before: [old settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBgrR.png)

Specifications:

> Visual Studio Code
>
> Version: 1.31.1
>
> Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
>
> Node.js: 10.2.0
>
> OS: Windows 10 Professional, Update: 1908

I am glad if anyone can help me solving that problem.

Comment: reinstall it and restart your machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code. How to open JSON settings with defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785520/vs-code-how-to-open-json-settings-with-defaults)

Comment: Last answer in the duplicate above.

Comment: @Mark, thank you it was indeed a duplicate sorry. I fixed it with the answer.